# Leaderboard android Google Play Game

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I would like to add a leaderboard to my android game.
Of course the easiest is to use Google Paly Game. But I'm afraid my users won't like being obliged to install Google play Game.
Can we avoid this installation?
Is it really a bad experience for the users? 
Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards), when you add Leaderboards in an Android game, installing and [setting-up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) is required.

But, AFAIK, your users only need to have Google Play Services for that game feature which is already installed by default on all Android devices. So, your users won't be obliged to install it.

See this [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104842/is-it-safe-to-uninstall-google-play-services-app) and this [blog](https://www.androidpit.com/google-play-services-what-is-it-and-what-is-it-for) for additional insights.